# Installing Yii2 with composer [ErrorException] Undefined index

Tags: composer-php, yii2, putty

**1)** Installed Composer on my Qnap NAS through Putty with the following command:

```
curl -sS -k https://getcomposer.org/installer | /mnt/ext/opt/apache/bin/php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

**2)** Updated composer:

```
/mnt/ext/opt/apache/bin/php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"
```

**3)** Installed Yii2:

```
/mnt/ext/opt/apache/bin/php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.3
```

The advanced folder has been created but without the `vendor` folder. Composer gives the following error:

> - Loading composer repositories with package information
> - Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> [ErrorException] Undefined index: owner

**Update**
Error with -vvv

```
Exception trace:
() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/GitHubDriver.php:409
Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/GitHubDriver.php:409
Composer\Repository\Vcs\GitHubDriver->fetchRootIdentifier() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/GitHubDriver.php:61
Composer\Repository\Vcs\GitHubDriver->initialize() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/VcsRepository.php:86
Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->getDriver() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AbstractAssetVcsRepository.php:118
Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetVcsRepository->initDriver() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:38
Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository->initialize() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:170
Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:104
Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/Util.php:58
Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\Util::addRepositoryInstance() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/Util.php:39
Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\Util::addRepository() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AbstractAssetsRepository.php:139
Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository->whatProvides() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:191
Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:180
Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:161
Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromPackage() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:273
Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromJobs() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:324
Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->getRulesFor() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:172
Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:505
Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:230
Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:140
Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
require() at /share/MD0_DATA/Web/composer.phar:25
```

Comment: Did you run `composer update` in project folder?

Comment: Yes tried that, same error..

Comment: I've tried your example and everything worked fine for me (yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.3) was used).
Info from your composer output would be helpful.

Also for more information, try to add `-vvv` (high verbosity) option to your composer commands.

Comment: Updated with the exception trace